# Laravel request being blocked with 401 error

Tags: laravel, twilio

I'm working on laravel project using Twilio number to receive MMS with files attached to it, and with every MMS the error (  11200 - HTTP retrieval failure ) appears in my webhook debugger and give me this message:- with error number 401

[Twilio 11200 error description](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/11200).

My controller

```php
    <?php
    
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use App\MMSMedia;
    use App\Services\MediaMessageService\IMediaMessageService;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Illuminate\Http\Response;
    use Magyarjeti\MimeTypes\MimeTypeConverter;
    use Twilio\Rest\Client;
    use Twilio\Twiml;
    
    class MessagingController extends Controller
    {
        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | Messaging Controller
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        |
        | This controller receives messages from Twilio and makes the media available
        | via the /images url.
        */
    
        protected $twilio;
        protected $accountSid;
        protected $twilioNumber;
        protected $twilioNumberSid;
        /**
         * Create a new controller instance.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->accountSid = env('TWILIO_SID');
            $this->twilioNumber = env('TWILIO_NUMBER');
            $this->twilioNumberSid = env('TWILIO_NUMBER_SID');
            $authToken = env('TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN');
    
            $this->twilio = new Client($this->accountSid, $authToken);
        }
    
        public function handleIncomingSMS(Request $request, IMediaMessageService $mediaService)
        {
            $converter = new MimeTypeConverter;
            $NumMedia = (int)$request->input('NumMedia');
            $FromNumber = $request->input('From');
            $MessageSid = $request->input('MessageSid');
    
            for ($i=0; $i < $NumMedia; $i++) {
                $mediaUrl = $request->input("MediaUrl$i");
                $MIMEType = $request->input("MediaContentType$i");
                $fileExtension = $converter->toExtension($MIMEType);
                $mediaSid = basename($mediaUrl);
    
                $media = $mediaService->getMediaContent($mediaUrl);
    
                $filename = "$mediaSid.$fileExtension";
    
                $mediaData = compact('mediaSid', 'MessageSid', 'mediaUrl', 'media', 'filename', 'MIMEType');
                $mmsMedia = new MMSMedia($mediaData);
                $mmsMedia->save();
            }
    
            $response = new Twiml();
            $messageBody = $NumMedia == 0 ? 'Send us an image!' : "Thanks for the $NumMedia images.";
            $message = $response->message([
                'from' => $request->input('To'),
                'to' => $FromNumber
            ]);
            $message->body($messageBody);
    
            return (string)$response;
        }
    
        public function deleteMediaFromTwilio($mediaItem)
        {
            return $this->twilio->api->accounts($this->accountSid)
                ->messages($mediaItem['MessageSid'])
                ->media($mediaItem['mediaSid'])
                ->delete();
        }
    
        public function allMedia()
        {
            $mediaItems = MMSMedia::all();
            return $mediaItems;
        }
    
        public function getMediaFile($filename, Response $response)
        {
            $media = MMSMedia::where('filename', $filename)->firstOrFail();
            $fileContents = $media['media'];
            $MessageSid = $media['MessageSid'];
            $mediaSid = $media['mediaSid'];
            $MIMEType = $media['MIMEType'];
    
            $media->delete();
            $this->deleteMediaFromTwilio(compact('mediaSid', 'MessageSid'));
    
            return response($fileContents, 200)
                ->header('Content-Type', $MIMEType);
        }
    
        public function config()
        {
            return ['twilioNumber' => $this->twilioNumber];
        }
    }
```

database migration is

```php
    <?php
    
    use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
    use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
    
    class CreateMMSMediaTable extends Migration
    {
        /**
         * Run the migrations.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function up()
        {
            Schema::create('m_m_s_media', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->id();
                $table->timestamps();
                $table->string('mediaSid')->index();
                $table->string('MessageSid')->index();
                $table->string('mediaUrl')->index();
                $table->binary('media');
                $table->string('filename')->index();
                $table->string('MIMEType');
            });
        }
    
        /**
         * Reverse the migrations.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function down()
        {
            Schema::dropIfExists('m_m_s_media');
        }
    }
```

my route in api.php file is

```php
    <?php
    
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
    
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | API Routes
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
    | routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
    | is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
    |
    */
    
    Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
        return $request->user();
    });
    
    Route::get('/config', 'MessagingController@config');
    
    Route::get('/media', 'MessagingController@allMedia');
    
    Route::get('/media/{filename}', 'MessagingController@getMediaFile');
    
    Route::post('/incoming', 'MessagingController@handleIncomingSMS');
```

MediaMessageService.php file

```
<?php

namespace App\Services\MediaMessageService;

class MediaMessageService implements IMediaMessageService
{
    public function getMediaContent($mediaUrl)
    {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $mediaUrl);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

        // Option to follow the redirects, otherwise it will return an XML
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        $media = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $media;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code you are using that results in this error? You say you are getting a 401 error, that's normally an authentication issue, are you trying to validate the webhook from Twilio or is there another authentication check being done?

Comment: I shared my code, And I hope you can help me

Comment: I'm not a Laravel developer, so I need to ask you about how this works to see if it is a problem. In your routes, you set up middleware for auth, does that affect just the `/user` route or all of the routes in that file? Are you able to load `/media` or `/config` without any logging in/authentication?

Comment: Okay, I will make a revision on this part of code, Until that what i suppose to write in webhook field in my Twilio phone number settings in Twilio.com?

Comment: in fact i'm so happy with your help

Comment: You have the right thing in your webhook field, you just need to make sure that your application isn't blocking access to that endpoint.

Comment: I fixed the error in my routes ( middleware for auth ) thank you so much, But when I send a message to my Twilio phone number to test it, it gives me error with number 405 ( method not supported )

Comment: In your phone number config, make sure the webhook is set to make a `POST` request to your endpoint.

Comment: ok, I will go there now

Comment: I went to my Twilio phone number and be sure that is POST request, What now?

Comment: Are you still getting a 405 error from the webhook?

Comment: yes i still have error 405

Comment: In your API routes you have `Route::post('/incoming', 'MessagingController@handleIncomingSMS');` according to your code above, and Twilio is making a `POST` request to your webhook, which you have verified. Is Twilio set up to make the request to the right endpoint, the `/incoming` endpoint? Are you able to make a request to your webhook endpoint yourself, using `curl` or Postman?

Comment: sorry philnash, i can not understand your last comment, but i will put code for using curl

Comment: I am just trying to confirm that nothing else has changed in your application and that the route should still be a POST request to `/incoming`. Are you able to make a request to your application yourself using curl or Postman?

Comment: I did not change the POST method in my route, in fact it is the first time to use Twilio and receive files from Twilio into my database, So i don't know how I make request to my application using curl or postman, I will search about that right now, I'm so sorry

Comment: I did postman request and the message did not send to my phone number with error 404 not found

Comment: I fixed my phone number in PostMan and send message to my phone number from Twilio phone numberagain and i received a message successfully

Comment: I meant to make the request to your application, not to Twilio. You need to see how your application responds to requests so you can fix your app.

Comment: okay i will make a request to my app, Sorry about missunderstanding, in webhook field in Twilio phone number config, I wrote my app URL is that correct or I suppose to stay on the default value of webhook which is https://demo.twilio.com/welcome/sms/reply?

Comment: You should write your app URL in the webhook URL field. That’a the only way Twilio will call your app when you receive an incoming message. Have you managed to make a request to your app via curl yet?

Comment: I'm trying to make a request to my app via Postman, But I not finished yet, I make something wrong and still working

Comment: I changed the POST method To GET method in Twilio phone number config ( just for trying ) and send MMS, The error 405 changed to  12200 - Schema validation warning, What does it mean?

Comment: That means that your application isn't returning XML in the format that Twilio expects. Can you show me the response body that you returned that caused this warning?

Comment: okay I will send it

Comment: do you mean that code

Comment: What did your application send back to Twilio? What was in the response body?

Comment: in fact i do not know what is that at all, so sorry I'm very new on this process

Comment: I do not know if the response body put in Twilio, or i suppose to create a XML file in my app

Comment: When a request is made to an endpoint in your application, your application does something with the request then responds with a response. In your code above you have `return (string)$response;` at the end of your `handleIncomingSMS` method. I am asking what is the content of that response.

Comment: I'm asking what the response is, because your code actually looks correct and that it is returning XML ([TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/twiml)). But if Twilio is notifying you of a 405 error, then perhaps the response isn't correct and we ned to inspect it.

Comment: I see, I will search about this point now

Comment: I made a lot of search to write the code above and many parts i'm still working to understand it, I'm so grateful to you and hope you can help me creating response body

Comment: You are already creating a response body. I just need to know what it is. How are you testing your webhooks with Twilio? Are you using a tunnel like ngrok?

Comment: no i do not use ngrok

Comment: So how are you testing the webhooks with Twilio?

Comment: I will go to ngrok and try to test my webhook

Comment: You don't have to use ngrok. I am interested in how you are doing the testing, so that I can make other suggestions.

Comment: okay tell me the easiest way to test my webhook?

Comment: Can you tell me how you were testing it first? It might also help to know what you have been doing.

Comment: i did not know that i can test my webhook, So i did not test it, I get started directly to deal with Twilio, I sent MMS with files attached to Twilio phone number and trying to store the files into my database inside my app

Comment: I meant how did you test it with Twilio. How are you creating a URL that Twilio can access your app. Are you just deploying your application to a server?

Comment: yes I just deploy the app to a mocha host server and set the URL  into Twilio

Comment: I think this might be better if we talk about this privately for a bit. Can you email me at philnash@twilio.com and I'll try to help.

Comment: yes please i will email you